# How to get Powershell to read 2 files per subfolder?

Tags: powershell

I currently have a Main folder with sub folders in another sub folders containing .wav file.

```
C:\TEST\Main Folder

  |Folder A
     |Folder A.1 
        |1.wav
        |2.wav
        |3.wav
        |4.wav

   |Folder B
     |Folder B.1 
        |1.wav
        |2.wav
        |3.wav
        |4.wav
```

I need Powershell to **randomly select and play 2** .wav file **FROM EACH** subfolder for 15 seconds and IF there is an audio, it will tagged a "Yes" ELSE "No". These results are then exported to a CSV.

However based on this code I managed to locate (and I added some of mine). I only get results for 2 .wav files in **TOTAL**. It should be 2 .wav **FROM EACH** subfolders

I can't seem to figure out the code:

```
# Test .wav Files
Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationCore
$mediaPlayer = New-Object system.windows.media.mediaplayer
$myDirectory = "C:\TEST\Main Folder"
$OUTPUT_CSV = "C:\TEST\Main Folder\Test_Audio.csv"

$numFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path $myDirectory -Filter *.WAV).Count

clear-host;

Write-Host 

"
There are:

$numFiles .wav files detected

"

Read-host -prompt 'Press ENTER to start the Testing - These .wav files will be played for approximately 15 secs for validation. You may hear these play on your laptop/computer (There may be a slight delay due to the network)'

Get-ChildItem -Path $myDirectory -Recurse -Filter '*.wav' | Get-Random -count 2 | `
Foreach-Object{

$Path = $_.FullName
$Folder = $_.Directory.Parent.BaseName
$FolderName = $_.Directory.BaseName
$Filename = $_.Name
$mediaPlayer.open("$Path")
$mediaPlayer.Play()

Start-Sleep 15

    if ($mediaPlayer.HasAudio -eq "True" -and $mediaPlayer.Position -gt "00:00:00"){
        $retVal = "Yes"
        $mediaPlayer.Stop()
    }
    else{
        $retVal = "No"
        $mediaPlayer.Stop()
    }
    #return $retVal

$Path| Sort-Object $Folder | Select-Object `

    @{n="Parent Folder";e={$Folder}},`
    @{n="Subfolder";e={$Foldername}},`
    @{n="Link to File";e={$Path}},`
    @{n="Playing?";e={$retVal}}`

} | Export-Csv $OUTPUT_CSV -NoTypeInformation 

Write-Host 

"

Testing Complete

Extract saved here

$OUTPUT_CSV 

The Extract will automatically open now.

"

# start Excel
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application

#open file
$WorkBook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($OUTPUT_CSV)

#make it visible (just to check what is happening)
$excel.Visible = $true


Read-host -prompt "Please check the CSV extract. Press enter to complete this process..."
clear-host;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for what you are after, this seems a bit out of whack. 
Taking your code and tweaking that to only go for the basic part of getting the file and the listing into a CSV file.

```
# Test .wav Files
Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationCore
$mediaPlayer = New-Object system.windows.media.mediaplayer
$myDirectory = "D:\Temp\ParentFolder"
$OUTPUT_CSV = "D:\Temp\ParentFolder\Test_Audio.csv"

<#
If you are after 2 wav files per folder, why are you only asking for the count here?
Each folder may have a different count and file name, right? 
#>

# $numFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path $myDirectory -Filter *.WAV).Count


foreach (
            $Dir in Get-ChildItem -Path $myDirectory -Recurse -Filter '*.wav' | 
            select -ExpandProperty DirectoryName -Unique
        ) 

        {
            $numFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir -Filter *.WAV).Count

            Read-host -prompt "
            `nThe folder $Dir contains a total of $numFiles wav files.`n
            Press ENTER to start the Testing`n
            These .wav files will be played for 
            approximately 15 secs for validation. You may hear these play on your 
            laptop/computer (There may be a slight delay due to the network)
            "
            Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir | 
            Get-Random -Count 2
        }

<#

Also, note that gets random will not always give you that could be depending on the number for total files you may have in a folder and when/where you call it.

Example: 
Each of my folders only have 3 wav files.

# Results

The folder D:\Temp\ParentFolder contains a total of 3 wav files.

            Press ENTER to start the Testing

            These .wav files will be played for 
            approximately 15 secs for validation. You may hear these play on your 
            laptop/computer (There may be a slight delay due to the network)
            : 



    Directory: D:\Temp\ParentFolder


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                         
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                         
d-----        12-Feb-20     12:37                ChildFolder                                                                                                  
-a----        28-Aug-07     13:08        2646058 ThumperLong.wav                                                                                              


The folder D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ChildFolder contains a total of 3 wav files.

            Press ENTER to start the Testing

            These .wav files will be played for 
            approximately 15 secs for validation. You may hear these play on your 
            laptop/computer (There may be a slight delay due to the network)
            : 



    Directory: D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ChildFolder


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        23-Apr-99     18:22         668440 WELCOM98.WAV
d-----        12-Feb-20     12:37                GrandchildFolder


The folder D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ChildFolder\GrandchildFolder contains a total of 3 wav files.

            Press ENTER to start the Testing

            These .wav files will be played for 
            approximately 15 secs for validation. You may hear these play on your 
            laptop/computer (There may be a slight delay due to the network)
            : 



    Directory: D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ChildFolder\GrandchildFolder


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        28-Aug-07     13:08        2646058 ThumperLong.wav
-a----        28-Aug-07     13:05         683670 ThumperShort.wav

So, to avoid this, do this...
#>


foreach (
            $Dir in Get-ChildItem -Path $myDirectory -Recurse -Filter '*.wav' | 
            select -ExpandProperty DirectoryName -Unique
        ) 

        {
            $numFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir -Filter *.WAV).Count

            Read-host -prompt "
            `nThe folder $Dir contains a total of $numFiles wav files.`n
            Press ENTER to start the Testing`n
            These .wav files will be played for 
            approximately 15 secs for validation. You may hear these play on your 
            laptop/computer (There may be a slight delay due to the network)
            "
            Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir -file | 
            Get-Random -Count 2
        } 

<#
# Results

The folder D:\Temp\ParentFolder contains a total of 3 wav files.

            Press ENTER to start the Testing

            These .wav files will be played for 
            approximately 15 secs for validation. You may hear these play on you
r 
            laptop/computer (There may be a slight delay due to the network)
            : 



    Directory: D:\Temp\ParentFolder


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                          
----                -------------         ------ ----                          
-a----        23-Apr-99     18:22         668440 WELCOM98.WAV                  
-a----        28-Aug-07     13:08        2646058 ThumperLong.wav               


The folder D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ChildFolder contains a total of 3 wav files.

            Press ENTER to start the Testing

            These .wav files will be played for 
            approximately 15 secs for validation. You may hear these play on your 
            laptop/computer (There may be a slight delay due to the network)
            : 



    Directory: D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ChildFolder


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                          
----                -------------         ------ ----                          
-a----        28-Aug-07     13:05         683670 ThumperShort.wav              
-a----        28-Aug-07     13:08        2646058 ThumperLong.wav               


The folder D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ChildFolder\GrandchildFolder contains a total of
 3 wav files.

            Press ENTER to start the Testing

            These .wav files will be played for 
            approximately 15 secs for validation. You may hear these play on you
r 
            laptop/computer (There may be a slight delay due to the network)
            : 



    Directory: D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ChildFolder\GrandchildFolder


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                          
----                -------------         ------ ----                          
-a----        28-Aug-07     13:05         683670 ThumperShort.wav              
-a----        28-Aug-07     13:08        2646058 ThumperLong.wav

Since you are looping thru file, put the Export -Append in the loop, not outside. THat error you are gettings is because the file creation is not valid. 
#>

foreach (
            $Dir in Get-ChildItem -Path $myDirectory -Recurse -Filter '*.wav' | 
            select -ExpandProperty DirectoryName -Unique
        ) 

        {
            $numFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir -Filter *.WAV).Count

            Read-host -prompt "
            `nThe folder $Dir contains a total of $numFiles wav files.`n
            Press ENTER to start the Testing`n
            These .wav files will be played for 
            approximately 15 secs for validation. You may hear these play on your 
            laptop/computer (There may be a slight delay due to the network)
            "
            Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir | 
            Select-Object -Property Directory, PSChildName, FullName | 
            Get-Random -Count 2 | 
            Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation  -Path $OUTPUT_CSV -Append
        }

Import-Csv -Path $OUTPUT_CSV

# Results
<#
Directory                                         PSChildName                FullName                                                                    
---------                                         -----------                --------                                                                    
D:\Temp\ParentFolder                              ParentWELCOM98.WAV         D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ParentWELCOM98.WAV                                     
D:\Temp\ParentFolder                              ParentThumperLong.wav      D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ParentThumperLong.wav                                  
D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ChildFolder                  ChildThumperShort.wav      D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ChildFolder\ChildThumperShort.wav                      
D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ChildFolder                  ChildThumperLong.wav       D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ChildFolder\ChildThumperLong.wav                       
D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ChildFolder\GrandchildFolder GrandchildWELCOM98.WAV     D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ChildFolder\GrandchildFolder\GrandchildWELCOM98.WAV    
D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ChildFolder\GrandchildFolder GrandchildThumperShort.wav D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ChildFolder\GrandchildFolder\GrandchildThumperShort.wav
#>


"
`nTesting Complete and is saved here. The extract will automatically open now.
"
# Open file - csv in MS Excel
Start-Process -FilePath 'excel.exe' -ArgumentList $OUTPUT_CSV
```

Though, I am not really sure why the verbose text prompt in your effort, since if they have the Excel file, closing that ends the use case, and you have not shown code that really does anything after that. So, that last Read-Host is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get random items from each directory. Change:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $myDirectory -Recurse -Filter '*.wav' | Get-Random -count 2 | `
Foreach-Object{

$Path = $_.FullName
$Folder = $_.Directory.Parent.BaseName
$FolderName = $_.Directory.BaseName
$Filename = $_.Name
$mediaPlayer.open("$Path")
$mediaPlayer.Play()

Start-Sleep 15

    if ($mediaPlayer.HasAudio -eq "True" -and $mediaPlayer.Position -gt "00:00:00"){
        $retVal = "Yes"
        $mediaPlayer.Stop()
    }
    else{
        $retVal = "No"
        $mediaPlayer.Stop()
    }
    #return $retVal

$Path| Sort-Object $Folder | Select-Object `

    @{n="Parent Folder";e={$Folder}},`
    @{n="Subfolder";e={$Foldername}},`
    @{n="Link to File";e={$Path}},`
    @{n="Playing?";e={$retVal}}`

} | Export-Csv $OUTPUT_CSV -NoTypeInformation
```

To:

```
foreach ($Dir in Get-ChildItem -Path $myDirectory -Recurse -Filter '*.wav' | select -ExpandProperty DirectoryName -Unique) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir | Get-Random -Count 2 | Foreach-Object {
        $Path = $_.FullName
        $Folder = $_.Directory.Parent.BaseName
        $FolderName = $_.Directory.BaseName
        $Filename = $_.Name
        $mediaPlayer.open("$Path")
        $mediaPlayer.Play()

        Start-Sleep 15

            if ($mediaPlayer.HasAudio -eq "True" -and $mediaPlayer.Position -gt "00:00:00"){
                $retVal = "Yes"
                $mediaPlayer.Stop()
            }
            else{
                $retVal = "No"
                $mediaPlayer.Stop()
            }
            #return $retVal

        $Path| Sort-Object $Folder | Select-Object `

            @{n="Parent Folder";e={$Folder}},`
            @{n="Subfolder";e={$Foldername}},`
            @{n="Link to File";e={$Path}},`
            @{n="Playing?";e={$retVal}}`

    } | Export-Csv $OUTPUT_CSV -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

Comment: Thanks! @t1meless. I tried it. Getting this error:

Export-Csv : Cannot append CSV content to the following file: C:\TEST\Main Folder\Test_Audio.csv. The 
appended object does not have a property that corresponds to the following column: Parent Folder. To continue with mismatched properties, add the -Force parameter, and 
then retry the command.

Comment: At line:53 char:9
+     } | Export-Csv $OUTPUT_CSV -NoTypeInformation -Append
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Parent Folder:String) [Export-Csv], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotAppendCsvWithMismatchedPropertyNames,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand

Comment: Does adding the -Force parameter help?